# My if-statement doesnt work. What did I do wrong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Probably just some dumb minor mistake that I'm too stupid to see right now, but it really bothers me.
I have this little game I'm working on in Unity and I wrote a method that is basically supposed to start the next level:

```
public void ButtonNextLevel()
{
    string currentScene = Convert.ToString(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    char[] currentSceneChars = new char[currentScene.Length];
    int stringLength = currentScene.Length;
    int levelIndex;

    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(currentScene))
    {
        sr.Read(currentSceneChars, 0, currentScene.Length - 2);
    }
    string levelIdentifier = new string(currentSceneChars);
    Debug.Log(levelIdentifier);

    if(levelIdentifier == "Level")
    {
        levelIndex = currentScene[stringLength - 1];
        Debug.Log(levelIndex);
        string nextSceneName = "Level " + (levelIndex + 1).ToString();
        if(SceneManager.GetSceneByName(nextSceneName).IsValid())
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(nextSceneName);
        }
        else {GameWon();}
    }
}
public void GameWon()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene("GameWon");
}
```

The main Problem seems to be the `if(levelIdentifier == "Level")` statement. If I get to the point where this script is executed, I do get a response from `Debug.Log(levelIdentifier);` (which clearly states `"Level"`), but not from `Debug.Log(levelIndex);`:
[Debug Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMDfG.png)
I don't understand why the if-statement isn't executed even though the requirements are met.

Comment: The entire beginning of your code is very confusing. It seems you are trying to extract a substring, but in a very convoluted and inefficient way?

Comment: And I suspect that due to the `currentSceneChars` being larger than the text you wrote into it the resulting `levelIdentifier` string has some invisible characters appended at the end, causing your `levelIdentifier == "Level"` to return `false`. You should probably just use `string levelIdentifier = currentScene.Substring(0, currentScene.Length - 2);` instead of what you are doing

Comment: @UnholySheep yes. Basically, my level scenes are called "Level 1", "Level 2", etc. What I'm trying here is to get the first 5 char of the scene name to find out if it is a level, then use the last char to find out what level it is.

Comment: @UnholySheep Substring did it, works now, thank you!

Comment: @Randomdud3 highly recommend to work with Guru Stron's answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do get a response from Debug.Log(levelIdentifier); (which clearly states "Level")

Are you sure that there is no whitespace characters in the debug output (like space or something)? Try adding `Debug.Log(levelIdentifier.Length);` also.

As for `if` statement it seems like a very convoluted way to check if string starts with some prefix. Since [`Scene.name`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene-name.html) is already a `string` try using [`stringStartsWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.startswith?view=net-6.0) (another potentially useful one is [`string.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-6.0)):

```cs
var sceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
if(sceneName.StartsWith("Level"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Following up, should use `int levelIndex = int.Parse(sceneName.Split(' ')[1]);`

Comment: @Lyrca yes, seems like a good idea.

Comment: @Lyrca good idea, but I ended up going with `int currentLevelBuildIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex; SceneManager.LoadScene(currentLevelBuildIndex + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

In your levelIdentifier there are 2 null chars (\0) always will append.
so levelIdentifier has has 2 '\0' chars in the end. that is why if statement fails

that is because you initialize `char[] currentSceneChars = new char[currentScene.Length];` with full length of input string but not used last 2 slots of the char array. so those 2 chars kept as null